Differentiability of $F(t) = \int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx$ for $\alpha >2$
By Leibnitz integral rule , $F_n(t) = \int_0^n \frac{\cos(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx$ is differentiable for all $n>0$ but what happens if $n \to \infty$?
By Theorem $7.17$ in Rudin's PMA, it suffices to show that  $F_n'(t) = \int_0^n \frac{d}{dt}\frac{\cos(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx = \int_0^n -\frac{x \sin(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx$ converges uniformly on every closed interval $[a,b]$ as $n\to \infty$.
This is where I am stuck. How do I show this?

Is there any bound for $\alpha$?

Yes. My bad. It's greater than 2.


Lemma 1: for $(a,\alpha,x)\in \Bbb R^+\times\Bbb R^{\ge 2}\times\Bbb R^{\ge 1}$ we have
$$
\left|\frac{x}{1+x^\alpha}-\frac{x+a}{1+(x+a)^\alpha}\right|\le \frac{a\alpha}{x^\alpha}.$$


Proof: Define $y=\left(\frac{x}{1+x^\alpha}-\frac{x+a}{1+(x+a)^\alpha}\right)x^\alpha$. Obviously, $\frac{x}{1+x^\alpha}$ is decreasing for $x\ge 1$ and $\alpha\ge 2$. This deduces that $y\ge 0$. Also,
$$
y
{=
\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{1+x^\alpha}-\frac{x^{\alpha+1}+ax^\alpha}{1+(x+a)^\alpha}
\\\le
\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{1+x^\alpha}-\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{1+(x+a)^\alpha}
\\=
x^{\alpha+1}\frac{(x+a)^\alpha-x^\alpha}{(1+x^\alpha)(1+(x+a)^\alpha)}
\\\le
x^{\alpha+1}\frac{(x+a)^\alpha-x^\alpha}{x^\alpha(x+a)^\alpha}
\\=
a\frac{x}{a}\frac{\left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)^\alpha-\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)^\alpha}{\left(1+\frac{x}{a}\right)^\alpha}.
}
$$
By defining $g(x)=x\frac{(1+x)^\alpha-x^\alpha}{(1+x)^\alpha}$ for $x\ge0$ and $\alpha\ge 2$ we have
$$
g'(x)
=
1-\frac{\alpha x^{\alpha}+x^{\alpha}+x^{\alpha+1}}{(1+x)^{\alpha+1}}.
$$
Let us denote the root of $g'(x)$ by $x_0$. Clearly, $\frac{\alpha x_0^{\alpha}+x_0^{\alpha}+x_0^{\alpha+1}}{(1+x_0)^{\alpha+1}}=1$ and we can write
$$
g(x_0)=\frac{\alpha x_0}{\alpha+1+x_0}\le \alpha,
$$
from which we conclude that $0\le y\le a\alpha$ and the proof is complete $\blacksquare$

Denote the error function $E_n(t)=|F_n'(t)-F_\infty'(t)|$. We try to find a proper upper bound for $E_n(t)$. By defining $k=\left\lceil\frac{nt}{2\pi}\right\rceil$ we have
$$
E_n(t)
{
=
\left|\int_n^\infty -\frac{x \sin(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx\right|
=
\left|\int_n^\infty \frac{x \sin(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx\right|
\\=
\left|\int_n^{\frac{2\pi k}{t}} \frac{x \sin(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx+\int_{\frac{2\pi k}{t}}^\infty \frac{x \sin(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx\right|
\\=
\left|\int_n^{\frac{2\pi k}{t}} \frac{x \sin(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx+\sum_{l=k}^\infty\int_{\frac{2\pi l}{t}}^{\frac{2\pi (l+1)}{t}} \frac{x \sin(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx\right|
\\=
\left|\int_n^{\frac{2\pi k}{t}} \frac{x \sin(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} dx
+
\sum_{l=k}^\infty\int_{\frac{2\pi l}{t}}^{\frac{2\pi l+\pi}{t}} 
\left(\frac{x}{1+x^\alpha}-\frac{x+\frac{\pi}{t}}{1+(x+\frac{\pi}{t})^\alpha}\right)\sin(tx) dx\right|
\\\le
\int_n^{\frac{2\pi k}{t}} \left|\frac{x \sin(tx)}{1+x^\alpha} \right|dx
+
\sum_{l=k}^\infty\int_{\frac{2\pi l}{t}}^{\frac{2\pi l+\pi}{t}} 
\left|\left(\frac{x}{1+x^\alpha}-\frac{x+\frac{\pi}{t}}{1+(x+\frac{\pi}{t})^\alpha}\right)\sin(tx) \right|dx
\\\le
\int_n^{\frac{2\pi k}{t}} x^{-1}dx
+
\sum_{l=k}^\infty\int_{\frac{2\pi l}{t}}^{\frac{2\pi l+\pi}{t}} 
\left|\frac{x}{1+x^\alpha}-\frac{x+\frac{\pi}{t}}{1+(x+\frac{\pi}{t})^\alpha} \right|dx
\\\le
\ln\frac{2\pi k}{nt}
+
\sum_{l=k}^\infty\int_{\frac{2\pi l}{t}}^{\frac{2\pi l+\pi}{t}} \frac{\pi\alpha}{tx^\alpha}dx
\\\le
\ln\frac{2\pi k}{nt}
+
\sum_{l=k}^\infty\int_{\frac{2\pi l}{t}}^{\frac{2\pi l+2\pi}{t}} \frac{\pi\alpha}{tx^\alpha}dx
\\=
\ln\frac{2\pi k}{nt}
+
\int_{\frac{2\pi k}{t}}^\infty \frac{\pi\alpha}{tx^\alpha}dx
\\=
\ln\frac{2\pi k}{nt}
+
\frac{\alpha}{2k(\alpha-1)}\left(\frac{t}{2\pi k}\right)^{\alpha-2}
\\=
\ln\frac{2\pi}{nt}\left\lceil\frac{nt}{2\pi}\right\rceil
+
\frac{\alpha}{2k(\alpha-1)}\left(\frac{t}{2\pi \left\lceil\frac{nt}{2\pi}\right\rceil}\right)^{\alpha-2}.
}
$$
From this point, the proof of uniform convergence is very easy $\blacksquare$.

I am sure that @Mostafa Ayaz' answer is closer to your question, but I however recommend a different approach to see differentiability very quickly. Note for $h \in \mathbb{R} \setminus \lbrace 0 \rbrace$:
$$
\int^{\infty}_0 \tfrac{\cos((t+h)x) - \cos(tx)}{h(1+x^\alpha)}~\mathrm{d}x
$$
This limit as $h \rightarrow 0$ is your desired derivative.
Also use Lipschitz-continuity of $\cos$ to estimate for a.e. $x \in [0, \infty)$:
$$
\left \lvert \tfrac{\cos((t+h)x) - \cos(tx)}{h(1+x^\alpha)} \right \rvert \leq \tfrac{x}{1+ x^\alpha}
$$
Then $\left( x \mapsto \tfrac{x}{1+ x^\alpha} \right) \in L^1\big([0, \infty) \big)$, because $\tfrac{x}{1+ x^\alpha} \in \mathcal{O}\big(x^{-\alpha+1} \big)$ and $\alpha - 1 >1$.
So by dominated convergence it holds that
$$
\lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \int^{\infty}_0 \tfrac{\cos((t+h)x) - \cos(tx)}{h(1+x^\alpha)}~\mathrm{d}x = \int^{\infty}_0 \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \tfrac{\cos((t+h)x) - \cos(tx)}{h(1+x^\alpha)}~\mathrm{d}x = \int^\infty_0 \tfrac{1}{1+x^\alpha} \tfrac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t} \cos(tx)~\mathrm{d}x
$$
